# Access is denied GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync in Dot Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

It is working fine in local machine but after deployment in Azure, I got an error.

> at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()     at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()     at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener()     at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.ReceiveCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)     at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.AuthorizeAsync(String userId, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)     at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Initializer initializer, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)     at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecrets clientSecrets, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)     at Salon.Web.Factories.GmailHelperFactory.GetGmailCode() in D:\Application\ArtSolutions\Salon Software\ArtSolutions.Salon.Web\Factories\GmailHelperFactory.cs:line 368

```
 public async Task GetGmailCode()
    {
        var userSession = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<UserSession>(CommonWebHelper.S_USERSESSION);
        try
        {
            string[] Scopes = {
                    GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly,
                    GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom,
                    GmailService.Scope.GmailModify
                };
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream($"client_secret.{_webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                //string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string credPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "credentials");
                await _logService.InsertInfoLogAsync(userSession.Id, (int)ModuleFeatures.SalesInvoice, credPath);
                //credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json");
                DsAuthorizationBroker.RedirectUri = _appSettings.Authentication.Google.AuthCodeRedirectURL;
                //await _logService.InsertInfoLogAsync(userSession.Id, (int)ModuleFeatures.SalesInvoice, DsAuthorizationBroker.RedirectUri);
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await _logService.InsertErrorLogAsync(userSession.Id, (int)ModuleFeatures.SalesInvoice, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync

Is designed for installed applications, that means that it will open the web browser window on the machine the code is running on.  In the case of your web application its trying to open the web browser on your web server which is not going to work.

GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync by default uses FileDataStore.  Azure isnt going to let you write to %appData%

For asp net you need to use something like this

Program.cs

```
    // This configures Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 for use in this app.
    services
        .AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
            // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
            // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
            o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
            // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
            o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = {YOUR_CLIENT_ID};
            options.ClientSecret = {YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET};
        });
}
```

## controller

```
/// <summary>
/// Lists the authenticated user's Google Drive files.
/// Specifying the <see cref="GoogleScopedAuthorizeAttribute"> will guarantee that the code
/// executes only if the user is authenticated and has granted the scope specified in the attribute
/// to this application.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="auth">The Google authorization provider.
/// This can also be injected on the controller constructor.</param>
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveReadonly)]
public async Task<IActionResult> DriveFileList([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = cred
    });
    var files = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
    var fileNames = files.Files.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    return View(fileNames);
}
```

I have a YouTube video [How to get a Google users profile information, with C#.](https://youtu.be/aqjglbdFGPk) and a blog post [Asp .net core 3 and Google login](https://www.daimto.com/asp-net-core-3-and-google-login/) which may help as well.

Comment: I tried all this things. All are working fine with local environment but after deployed, it hasn't.

Comment: Please define not working.  Do you have an error message.  This is from the official sample for asp .net.   Did you adjust the redirect uri for your hosted environment?

Comment: The offical Asp .net example can be found here : [Web applications (ASP.NET Core 3)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3)